# Which is more common, “un de ces jours” or “un de ces quatre matins”?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

I’ve seen both and never been sure if one was more old fashioned or less “courant” than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In text documents, *un de ces jours* is much more common, even when [including *un de ces quatre* in the comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un%20de%20ces%20jours%2Cun%20de%20ces%20quatre%20matins%2Cun%20de%20ces%20quatre&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cun%20de%20ces%20jours%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bun%20de%20ces%20jours%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUn%20de%20ces%20jours%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cun%20de%20ces%20quatre%20matins%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bun%20de%20ces%20quatre%20matins%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUn%20de%20ces%20quatre%20matins%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cun%20de%20ces%20quatre%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bun%20de%20ces%20quatre%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUn%20de%20ces%20quatre%3B%2Cc0) :

[image]

*Un de ces quatre*, being more colloquial, is certainly more frequent in spoken French than in books, but I believe *un de ces jours* still leads in this context although I have no data to back it up.

Comment: Note that "un de ces quatre" is significantly more common than the full "un de ces quatre matins" variant. Also that Google ngrams only accounts for occurences in books.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Indeed. Answer updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

"A un de ces quatre (matins)" is only used with good friends. While "A un de ces jours" can be said to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Tu le reverras "un de ces quatre (matins)" est plus familier et "un de ces quatre" encore plus.  "A un de ces jours!", c'est pour ne pas dire "Au revoir!"